# How to Use InsertLastId() in PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

how to use lastInsertId() using pdo, in my code.??

This is my code...

**Abstract.php**

```
<?php

require_once 'Database.php';

abstract class Abstract_controller extends Database
{
        /* ==================== POST ==================== */
        protected $post;
        public function showPosts()
        {
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM $this->post";
                $stmt = Database::prepare($sql);
                $stmt->execute();
                return $stmt->fetchAll();
        }

        public function showPostsE()
        {
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM $this->post WHERE id_artikel = :id_artikel";
                $stmt = Database::prepare($sql);
                $stmt->bindParam(':id_artikel', $stmt->lastInsertId('id_artikel'));
                $stmt-execute();
                return $stmt->fetch();
        }

        /* ==================== CATEGORIES ==================== */
        protected $categories;
        public function showCategories()
        {
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM $this->categories";
                $stmt = Database::prepare($sql);
                $stmt->execute();
                return $stmt->fetchAll();
        }
}

?>
```

**controller.php**

```
<?php

require_once 'Abstract_controller.php';

class Class_controller extends Abstract_controller
{
        /* ==================== POST ==================== */
        protected $post = "artikel";
        private $id_artikel;
        private $judul_artikel;
        private $isi_artikel;
        private $categories_artikel;

        public function setJudulArtikel($judul_artikel)
        {
                $this->judul_artikel = $judul_artikel;
        }

        public function setIsiArtikel($isi_artikel)
        {
                $this->isi_artikel = $isi_artikel;
        }

        public function setCategArtikel($categories_artikel)
        {
                $this->categories_artikel = $categories_artikel;
        }

        /* ==================== SAVE POSTS ==================== */
        public function savePosts()
        {
                $sql = "INSERT INTO artikel (id_artikel, judul_artikel, isi_artikel, status, categories)
                                VALUES (NULL, :judul_artikel, :isi_artikel, 'save', :categories_artikel)";
                $stmt = Database::prepare($sql);
                $stmt->bindParam(':judul_artikel', $this->judul_artikel);
                $stmt->bindParam(':isi_artikel', $this->isi_artikel);
                $stmt->bindParam(':categories_artikel', $this->categories_artikel);
                $stmt->lastInsertId(PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                return $stmt->execute();
        }

        /* ==================== PUBLISH POSTS ==================== */
        public function publishPosts()
        {
                $sql = "INSERT INTO artikel (id_artikel, judul_artikel, isi_artikel, status)
                                VALUES (NULL, :judul_artikel, :isi_artikel, 'publish')";
                $stmt = Database::prepare($sql);
                $stmt->bindParam(':judul_artikel', $this->judul_artikel);
                $stmt->bindParam(':isi_artikel', $this->isi_artikel);
                return $stmt->execute();
        }

        /* ==================== CATEGORIES ==================== */
        protected $categories = "categories";

}



?>
```

Comment: You should always post the code in your question instead of posting links. I've fixed it for you. But you still need to explain exactly what you're trying to do and what isn't working.

Comment: You should describe what exactly you want to do and how you tried to achieve this, instead of posting your whole code.

Comment: i want to create a cms like wordpress, but i confuse how to get id using lastInsertId() in my code

Answer (score 0):

For getting last inserted id, you should use `lastInsertId()` with **connection**, not with **statement**.

```
public function savePosts()
        {
                $sql = "INSERT INTO artikel (id_artikel, judul_artikel, isi_artikel, status, categories)
                                VALUES (NULL, :judul_artikel, :isi_artikel, 'save', :categories_artikel)";
                $stmt = Database::prepare($sql);
                $stmt->bindParam(':judul_artikel', $this->judul_artikel);
                $stmt->bindParam(':isi_artikel', $this->isi_artikel);
                $stmt->bindParam(':categories_artikel', $this->categories_artikel);
                $stmt->execute();

                return Database::lastInsertId();  // here you can return last inserted id
        }
```

Comment: i try it and i get error .

Fatal error: Call to undefined method Database::lastInsertId() in C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\cms-admin\controller\Class_controller.php on line 39